# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire, nsrangeexception

I am fetching the labels, text and image through API. When API has data , it shows without error. But when the API is nil, it throws error as:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty
>   NSArray'.

I need it to show null if API provides nil value but prevent from crash. Anyone out there please help to solve this issue in Swift 3. The code is given below:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class Instructors: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var fullName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var post: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var descriptionName: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var instructorImage: UIImageView!

    var dictDataContent:NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    var dictData:NSArray = NSArray()
    var dictprofile:NSDictionary = NSDictionary()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dictData = (dictDataContent.value(forKey: "instructors") as AnyObject) as! NSArray
        self.dictprofile = (dictData.object(at: 0) as AnyObject) as! NSDictionary
        let url:URL = URL(string: (self.dictprofile.value(forKey: "profile_image")) as! String)!
        SDWebImageManager.shared().downloadImage(with: url, options: [],progress: nil, completed: {[weak self] (image, error, cached, finished, url) in
            if self != nil {
              self?.instructorImage.image = image
            }
        })

        self.fullName.text = dictprofile.value(forKey: "full_name") as! String?
        self.post.text = dictprofile.value(forKey: "designation") as! String?
        self.descriptionName.text = dictprofile.value(forKey: "description") as! String?
    }

}
```

Comment: The error msg it self the reason,  check the array count then access the object from the array. Your 'dictDataContent' doesn't have any value or check the key 'instructors'

Comment: i have given all my codes down there. I checked condition for dictDataContent and it still throws same error and when I check for dictData it returns nil for all. I am beginner in swift. Please can you  elaborate in detail ?? plz..

Comment: @Tamannah why don't just check if dictData.count > 0 and then do what are you doing?

Comment: When i check dictate.count > 0 , it shows null for all given values also.

Answer (score 0):

So what I understand from your problem is ***your API might have data and sometimes no data***. This is the behavior of `Optionals` in swift. So you need to have `optional` variables for storing your data.

Changing your `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` variables to `optional` might help. Try the code below:

```
class Instructors: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var fullName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var post: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var descriptionName: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var instructorImage: UIImageView!

    var dictDataContent:NSDictionary?
    var dictData:NSArray?
    var dictprofile:NSDictionary?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dictData = dictDataContent?.value(forKey: "instructors") as? NSArray
        if let count = dictData?.count, count > 0 {
            dictprofile = dictData?.object(at: 0) as? NSDictionary
        }
        if let urlString = dictprofile?.value(forKey: "profile_image") as? String {
            if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
                SDWebImageManager.shared().downloadImage(with: url, options: [],progress: nil, completed: {[weak self] (image, error, cached, finished, url) in
                    if self != nil {
                        self?.instructorImage.image = image
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        fullName.text = dictprofile?.value(forKey: "full_name") as? String
        post.text = dictprofile?.value(forKey: "designation") as? String
        descriptionName.text = dictprofile?.value(forKey: "description") as? String
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it earlier.. It force me to delete optionals. Error as "Fix-it Delete "?"" @nayem

Comment: On which line do you get this "Fix-it"?

Comment: For every lines where i put "?" as your given codes above.

Comment: Okay you might have put `?` by yourself, right? Let's copy my whole code and paste it to your editor.

Comment: Error as:Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'NSArray'  and Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'NSDictionary'

Comment: You haven't made your variable declarations `optional`. Like: `var dictData:NSArray?`. That's why it isn't letting you to use `?` inside your viewDidLoad().

Comment: now all errors are cleared, i copied your codes. But again shows error as *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'

Comment: It shows error at ,, let url = URL(string: dictprofile?.value(forKey: "profile_image") as! String)    as Error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0*0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149069/discussion-between-nayem-and-tamannah).